# RØDE wishlist - What would you recommend? 

Tags: rode, gear, microphone, boom-pole, equipment

I must put together a wishlist of [RØDE](http://usa.rodemic.com/index.php) equipment (I can't yet say why). I'm okay on the accessories side, it's the mic choices my main concern. My priority is to have a descent kit to record sound effects (in the field mostly and in the studio secondly). Any advice?

So far, the [NT4](http://usa.rodemic.com/microphone.php?product=NT4) is definitely on my list. Added to that, I'm looking for a mic that would be good for high SPL, maybe along the lines of the [SM57](http://www.shure.com/proaudio/products/wiredmicrophones/us_pro_sm57-lc_content). I'm also looking for a nice shotgun. Does RØDE not do Lavaliers?

On the boompole front. Not sure whether to get the [mini](http://usa.rodemic.com/accessory.php?product=Mini-Boompole) one or the [normal](http://usa.rodemic.com/accessory.php?product=Boompole) one, the mini one would be good for the road, while the normal one would be good to double up for on-set uses. They both are the same size folded up but the mini is lighter. Any other crucial differences you know of?

Apart from the normal accessories like wind kits and cables, are there any specific items I should be looking at that RØDE does well? Do they not make inline pads?

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd get an NTG3 shotgun.  Sounds comparable to something like the Sanken CS-1 or 416 (even looks a bit like a 416 or KM81i).  I'd get the wind package they make for it too, unless you can pull off getting a rycote kit.

The NT4 is a nice mic, although I find myself wishing I could change polar patterns on it, and its heavy!! 9v power option on it is nice though, for the times I don't want to bring something as big as a 744T out with me. (and it comes with the 5pin XLR to 2x XLR output cable AND the 5pin xlr to 1/8" cable, which is nice.  So many companies make you buy accessories like that...)

I'd also get a pair of NT5s (they make a stereo matched pair) so you can do a stereo pattern other than the NT4's coincident X-Y.  Also always nice to have a few pencil mics laying around. Unfortunately, they don't make a stereo bar to go with it.

I'd get an NT2000 LDC.  Nice for studio work, such as studio sfx, VO, etc...  It's a very useful mic because it's so flexible (has continuously variable polar pattern). If you have carte blanche over all their products, I'd go ahead and get a Classic II as well. Really nice sounding tube LDC (although I can't think of much to use it for in a film setting other than VO work.  I suppose it might make for some nice studio sfx recordings.  Can't use it in the field though because of the power supply.

As far as accessories go, I'd stock up on their softies (WS7), maybe get a blimp kit with a windjammer (blimp / deadcat).  If you get an NT4, I'd also get the "Dead Kitten".  That mic is a really weird size and it's a pain to get a good windshield on it, so I'm sure it would prove itself quite useful.

They also make a nice little tripod mic stand that could come in handy.  As far as which boom pole to go with, I can't really help you there without knowing what it's for.  The small one limits what you can do, but is easier to travel with.

Hope this helps.  I've had a fair amount of experience with RØDE products, so let me know if you have any questions specific to a certain mic or something.

Comment: Oh right, no, they don't make lavs, but they've been expanding their product line quite a bit over the past 2 or 3 years, so I wouldn't be surprised to see one eventually

Comment: Really helpful answer... Thank you! I can see you've recorded a bunch in your life ;-) 

Comment: have you had any experience with the M3? It's a condenser, but it seems like a good alternative for the SM57 (from what I've read online). I'm looking for a mic I can use for high SPL. Maybe if I need to mic a car motor, gun or a really loud sound. 

Comment: I've not had a whole lot of experience with it, but I have used the NT3, which is the hypercardioid version of it.  Sounds fairly good (in the same way that a 57 sounds fairly good).  Obviously it's a lot more sensitive than the 57, and the high frequency response is a lot better too (the 57 only goes up to 15k!). Should be good for gun shots and other high transient noises (142db max spl i think).

Answer (score 2):

I had a Røde mini boompole and hated it, despite loving my NT1a, NTG2, and NT4 (with the limitations Colin outlined above). Overbuilt and way too heavy. I kicked it to the curb and went with a K-Tek aluminum boom that, while a tad shorter, is plenty for SFX gathering, still is a good price:performance value, and the knurling on the locking rings is easier on the hands/fingers. Røde's sweet spot, IMO, is in the large condenser area, which they do very well at very low prices.

Comment: Good to know. That K-Tek seems nice and the XLR runs through the pole, which is nice! However, the RØDE is free (can't beat that). 

Comment: Ya got me beat with "free!" :-)

Answer (score 1):

Well I'm not good with microphones but on the Boom pole front, I suggest you get the mini.  As you say, it's lighter and better for travelling, and you can use on set for very quick things if need be - at least you have it.  Then should you need a better one specifically for on-set then further on down the line you can get a normal boom pole?  Just a suggestion!

Comment: Thanks. That's what I figured. I don't do much on-set recording, and when I do, I hardly ever need to extend a boom that far anyway. If the film requires it, then I can always rent.  

Answer (score 1):

You have to add NTG2 shotgun mic on your wishlist and the mini boom pole suggested by Fiona Fung. The N4 is a good choise too.

Answer (score 1):

The Nt2a's are quite nice, for the price, for being multi pattern and the self noise is reaaally low. I really like them for ambiance recording, usually as a spaced omni pair, especially when there is no wind or when you can get away with just a sock.